# For lognormal data, what are necessary sample sizes for a difference in means between treatment / control

Tags: statistical-power, lognormal-distribution

Given a population to be divided between treatment / control, if I believe a variable is distributed lognormal in the population, how do I know what the necessary control size is in order to guarantee a difference in means is significant at some arbitrary level for a specific effect size?

(Reference to R or SAS example appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to express the smallest effect you want to be able to detect as a ratio of geometric means, you can work on the log scale and perform a standard sample size calculation for the case of two normal distributions.

Comment: 10 years later, I have a follow-up question: would you compute geometric standard deviation as well and incorporate it alongside the ratio of geo means for the effect size? Alternatively, transforming data with ln() function and calculating mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Onestop's answer, you'll need a means of doing power analysis.  You can check around the web for a power calculator that fits your particular test (*T*-test?).  Or you can download the free and pretty versatile program GPower.